# maven update project throws Nullpointer for Quarkus getting-started

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, quarkus

I follow this "getting started guide" from quarkus:
https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started

After step 4 the project is created.

I switched to my IDE (Eclipse 20.03) and imported the project as "existing maven project".

The import throws a NPE (without any further information where or what the stack trace was)

I tried to use Maven > Update Project but this also creates the NPE.

I made sure that the Maven implementation inside eclipse is the the same as outside (3.8.4) and also the JRE is set to the system JRE (JDK11)

How can I get Eclipse to import the created Maven project?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse: Eclipse 20.03 ? I would really suggest to upgrade your Eclipse version.  https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: @khmarbaise was correct. I updated Eclipse and this sorted the maven problem out. Now the project can be updated and it builds also in the IDE.